# How can I test the script-local functions of my plugin?

Tags: functions, plugin-development, unit-testing

I have the feeling that the answer is *you can't*, but I'd like to be sure about it.

[My plugin](https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ) has some `s:function-name` functions, and one `plugin-name#function-name` function that uses the former ones.

Is there a way to write unit tests for those `s:` functions? For instance, could I do it via Vader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I have internal functions that I want to test, I don't declare them as `s:` functions but with a different naming policy like `mypluginscope#_whatever()`. This way testing them is not an issue and I keep `s:functions` really internal.

Otherwise there is a way to find script-local functions from the name of the plugin. We have to find the ScriptNumbeR of the file (by analysing `execute(':scriptname')`, and then forge the function name with `<SNR>{thenumber}_{thefunctionname}`.

I've described the approach to obtain and reference such functions in two Q/A on SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49447600/15934
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39216373/15934

I did write that the SNR could be obtained for foobar.vim with:

```
let snr = matchstr(matchstr(split(execute('scriptnames'), "\n"), 'foobar.vim'), '^ *\d\+')
```

and then the function `s:foo` from foobar.vim could be used with

```
let Foo = function('<SNR>'.snr.'_foo')
echo Foo(42)
```

Note: I cannot tell whether this solution could be used with vader, but at least it should work perfectly with my [unit testing plugin for Vim Scripts](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-UT/) -- given the way it works: sourcing vim files and all.

Comment: The get-the-SNR approach works pretty well. I needed to match `autoload/foobar.vim`, which you couldn't know. Besides, `'^ *\d\+'` should be used instead of `'^\d\+'` because the numbers in the first column of `:scriptnames` are right aligned, so you get some leading space for those numbers with less digits than the maximum number.

Comment: I'm not surprised the pattern is not 100% correct ^^'. Actually since then I've _industrialized_ the search in [a function of my library plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/askvim.vim#L104).

Answer (score 0):

I have a [plugin that I use to do unit tests](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-unit-test) on my [vim-surround-funk plugin](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-surround-funk) (it can only check if the [contents of one buffer after applying some normal mode commands is identical to the contents of an 'expected output buffer'](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim_plugin_external_docs/tree/master/vim-surround-funk/unit_tests)). It's not documented, and I never really planned on releasing it for others to use, but it's only 250 lines of code so maybe you can [have a look at that](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-unit-test/blob/main/plugin/vim-unit-test.vim) and roll your own solution (or even just try to use my one). Another option is to change all your function names from s:myfunction() to regular MyFunction() and source the script directly.

Comment: Well, the point is that my plugin is not for editing text, but for editing windows layout, so there's no expected vs actual text.

Comment: @Enlico ah ok then maybe you can look for a real unit-testing vimscript framework like [this one](https://github.com/kana/vim-vspec) (although I don't know if it can handle window layouts). You might have to write your own set of functions to do it (if you deem it worth your time)